# create a UITableView inside UITableViewCell, different ways to display hierarchical data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Its something like

- UITableView
  -----UITableViewCell
  -----UITableViewCell
  -----UITableViewCell
  -----UITableViewCell
  ------------- UITableView
  ----------------------UITableViewCell
  ----------------------UITableViewCell
  ----------------------UITableViewCell
  ----------------------UITableViewCell
  -----UITableViewCell
  -----UITableViewCell

is this possible? If it is not possible what is the best way to display collection of tableviewcells inside others tableviewcells in one page not on the next screen.

what are the different ways to display hierarchical data?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common way to solve this is to use sections combined with the "next screen" approach, but you mentioned, you wouldn't like to do this. If you don't have many levels, just 2, then in this particular case you can use sections.

Now, if you have more than 2 levels, then you should subclass the UITableViewCell class and add a `NSInteger level` property and create your content in the cell according to this level property.